# Flutter optionally include / exclude parent widget in widget tree

Tags: flutter

I have this widget tree

```
return Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Container(
    child: Text("Child"),
  ),
);
```

Is there a way to remove a parent widget from the tree or conditionally include it?

For example if a state variable such as includeBlueContainer was false, I would like to not render the blue container (but show everything else).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I couldn't achieve an optionally include reusable widget but I've been using this pattern which does achieve what I wanted to achieve.  I haven't given this a great amount of thought but I still feel there is a better solution somewhere.

```
class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool isIncluded;
  MyContainer({this.child, this.isIncluded = true});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!isIncluded) return child;

    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Edit: I made a package out of this: https://pub.dev/packages/conditional_parent_widget

Which you can use like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:conditional_parent_widget/conditional_parent_widget.dart';

// ...

return ConditionalParentWidget(
  condition: includeBlueContainer,
  child: Text("Child"),
  parentBuilder: (Widget child) => Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: child,
  ),
);
```

Internally it is just:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class ConditionalParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ConditionalParentWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.condition,
    required this.child,
    required this.parentBuilder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final bool condition;
  final Widget Function(Widget child) parentBuilder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return condition ? this.parentBuilder(this.child) : this.child;
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice If you updated this package to also allow developers to conditionally use Parent A vs Parent B. Right now it is just parent A vs no parent.

Comment: I forgot about this package, take a look here: https://github.com/ltOgt/ltogt_utils_flutter/blob/c0534dd7a3934a746b6a0488e7b4e9b4f8490464/lib/src/widget/builder/conditional_parent_widget.dart

Comment: I did update the package now as well